Setup libstdc++ for a given gcc version
New to Linux here.
Already had gcc 11 and 12 on my ubuntu but compiled gcc-14 using following command:
./configure -v --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-14.1.0 --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --program-suffix=-14.1.0

then after  make && make install
I added gcc-14 to my list of available compilers using update-alternatives:
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/local/gcc-14.1.0/bin/gcc-14.1.0 14 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/local/gcc-14.1.0/bin/g++-14.1.0  --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/local/gcc-14.1.0/bin/gcov-14.1.0

However when compiling cpp code that use c++23 features I get link error:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.31' not found

I guess the libstdc++.so here is the one used for gcc-12 or gcc-11. libstdc++.so is available for gcc-14 at /usr/local/gcc-14.1.0/lib64/libstdc++.so
Is there a way to specify that gcc-14 should always use is own libstdc++ ? (Without specifying static path to the libstdc++ to use at compile time inside my cmake script)

OT: The --build, --host and --target configuration parameters are only needed for cross-compilation.

@Someprogrammerdude Good to know. Recompiling gcc without specifying target/build/host could resolve the problem ?

No, it's unrelated to the problem, but I don't think I had any problems with it myself when using update-alternatives... By the way, which version of Ubuntu are you using? Can't you install gcc-14 and g++-14 using apt? That's what I have done, but I don't remember if it's the default of 24.04 or I've added some repository for it.

my distrib is ubuntu 22 based. I don't have access to gcc-14 that's why I compiled it. Using update-alternatives gcc --version show as expected gcc 14.1.0. Maybe the problem is not what I think at first place ?

Xemuth: For future reference, OT in a comment is short for "off topic" and it means that it doesn't mean to solve or point at the problem at hand but may solve or indicate other problems with what's presented. "Unrelated" may also be used to tag comments with good info at times.

Fixed my problem by doing:
sudo apt remove gcc-11 gcc-12
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

New package gcc-13-base has been installed and everything is fine now.
N.B: Not specifying --prefix when compiling make GCC install correctly and totally elude this problem
